# Zend Mail using gmail SMTP

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

There are like 1000 posts on this, but somehow I cant get things to work. I use

```
$config = array('ssl' => 'tls',
            'auth' => 'login',
                'port' => 587,
                'username' => 'myusername@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'mypassword');

$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
```

and get a

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Unable to connect via TLS'
```

Using

```
$config = array('ssl' => 'ssl',
                'auth' => 'login',
                'port' => 465,
                'username' => 'myusername@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'mypassword');

$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
```

I am getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Could not open socket'
```

Btw, I am using xampp 1.7.7. Any help anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Gmail doesn't allow SSL/TLS. If you remove that line I believe the config above should work, assuming correct username and password.

Comment: I am not sure if the statement in this answer is absolutely correct. For me 'ssl' => 'tls' is necessary to send mails through gmail, otherwise i am getting the following exception: 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Comment: I agree with @DimitrisBaltas, google definitely requires ssl connection. It's really weird.

Comment: not sure, it does work, but google asks for an ssl connection.

Answer (score 1):

Find following in the php.ini file

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
//remove the semicolon in front, save and restart apache, then passed.
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: nopes, i saw a post on that but did not find that line in my php.ini, googled and found - OpenSSL is compiled and enabled in php 5.3 of XAMPP 1.7.2 and so no longer requires a separate extension dll.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this config array (it works for me):

```
$config = array(
   'ssl' => 'tls',
   'auth' => 'login',
   'port' => 25,
   'username' => 'myusername@gmail.com',
   'password' => 'mypassword');
```